# Detecting Windows 7 with Google Analytics

Tags: windows-7, google-analytics, user-agent

This question might belong on one of the other trilogies, but it sorta seemed to be the best place.

I have google analytics set up, but it doesn't seem to detect Windows 7. I'm on Win7 myself, so I know there should be at least some number of Win7-users.

The user agent for Win7 is NT 6.1, and google analytics have detected NT users, but I'm not sure if that's a coincidence or not...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Windows 7 is detected as Windows NT.

See [this issue](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=5fb851152ce75b96&hl=en).

You can submit a new bug [here](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/request.py?contact_type=knownissues).

Comment: no bug reporting form...hmm...crap.. Oh, well, they'll probably fix it when Win7 is released commercially.

Comment: I couldn't find NT anywhere but I was able to get a new Segment if you see my answer. Maybe things have changed since 2009.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just parse the user agent in the javascript block for NT 6.1?

Answer (score 1):

In 2017, you can add a Segment to match only Windows 7 by clicking New Segment, then Technology, then enter OS exactly matches `Windows`, and enter OS Version starts with `7`. Then click Save!

This is how it looks:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics only parses the User-Agent string. For instance, it is `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0)` for [IE8 on Windows 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/01/09/the-internet-explorer-8-user-agent-string-updated-edition.aspx).

> On Windows 7, IE8 will send the
>   User-Agent string with the new Windows
>   NT version token.
>
> (If you’re curious about why Windows 7
>   uses the version number “6.1”: the
>   short answer is that it improves
>   compatibility, and the longer answer
>   can be found over [on the Windows Team
>   Blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/windowsvista/archive/2008/10/14/why-7.aspx).)

Comment: Yeah, but Vista disguises itself as NT 6.0, which is picked up by Google Analytics as Vista, XP says it's NT 5.1 (XP 64bit as NT 5.2).